# Is it possible to get facebook user's name and main profile picture by url?

Tags: facebook

Looks like atm it is not allowed to do, because any requests like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user_name
```

return

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (user_name)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803,
      "fbtrace_id": "DhZmj6bMhSC"
   }
}
```

And to get user id, i need `access_token`, which can be retrieved only when user is going through oauth procedure.

So, there are no ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get any data without authorization, and there is no way to get the `username` anymore. You can only get the name (`first_name`, `last_name`). This call would return the name and the profile picture, with a User Token:

```
/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,picture&access_token=xxx
```

This is mostly for privacy reasons, users who did not authorize your App are none of your business and you would not be allowed to do anything with their data anyway.